# Lists and horizontal lines not working

Tags: html, css

After I added some CSS into my page I started experiencing some problems. The horizontal lines are aligned in the center by default and my lines are aligned in the left by default. Also, the numbers and the bullets of the lists are not appearing. Here's are the codes:
First, here's the code for the CSS menu I am using:

```
 * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    html {
        background-color: #000;
    }
    .container {
        margin: 0px auto;
        width: 98%;
    }

    /* general styles */
    .menu, .menu ul {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .menu {
        height: 58px;
    }
    .menu li {
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(#000000, #000000);
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(#000000, #000000);
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #292929), color-stop(100%, #000000));
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#000000, #000000);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(#000000, #FFFFFF);
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#000000');
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#000000')";
        background: linear-gradient(#000000, #000000);

        border-bottom: 2px solid #181818;
        border-top: 2px solid #303030;
        min-width: 300px;
    }
    .menu > li {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        position: fixed;
    }
    .menu > li:first-child {
        border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    }
    .menu a {
        border-left: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        color: #FFFFFF;
        display: block;
        font-family: 'Lucida Console';
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 40px;
        padding: 0 25px;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: none;
    }

    /* onhover styles */
    .menu li:hover {
        background-color: #1c1c1c;
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(#1c1c1c, #1b1b1b);
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(#1c1c1c, #1b1b1b);
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #1c1c1c), color-stop(100%, #1b1b1b));
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#1c1c1c, #1b1b1b);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(#1c1c1c, #1b1b1b);
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#1c1c1c', endColorstr='#1b1b1b');
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#1c1c1c', endColorstr='#1b1b1b')";
        background: linear-gradient(#1c1c1c, #1b1b1b);

        border-bottom: 2px solid #222222;
        border-top: 2px solid #1B1B1B;
    }
    .menu li:hover > a {
        border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
        border-left: 5px solid #009DFF;
        color: #009DFF;
    }

    /* submenu styles */
    .submenu {
        left: 0;
        max-height: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        z-index: 0;

        -webkit-perspective: 400px;
        -moz-perspective: 400px;
        -ms-perspective: 400px;
        -o-perspective: 400px;
        perspective: 400px;
    }
    .submenu li {
        opacity: 0;

        -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
        -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg);
        -ms-transform: rotateY(90deg);
        -o-transform: rotateY(90deg);
        transform: rotateY(90deg);

        -webkit-transition: opacity .4s, -webkit-transform .5s;
        -moz-transition: opacity .4s, -moz-transform .5s;
        -ms-transition: opacity .4s, -ms-transform .5s;
        -o-transition: opacity .4s, -o-transform .5s;
        transition: opacity .4s, transform .5s;
    }
    .menu .submenu li:hover a {
        border-left: 5px solid #009DFF;
        border-radius: 0;
        color: #009DFF;
    }
    .menu > li:hover .submenu, .menu > li:focus .submenu {
        max-height: 2000px;
        z-index: 10;
    }
    .menu > li:hover .submenu li, .menu > li:focus .submenu li {
        opacity: 1;

        -webkit-transform: none;
        -moz-transform: none;
        -ms-transform: none;
        -o-transform: none;
        transform: none;
    }

    /* CSS3 delays for transition effects */
    .menu li:hover .submenu li:nth-child(1) {
        -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
        -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
        -ms-transition-delay: 0s;
        -o-transition-delay: 0s;
        transition-delay: 0s;
    }
    .menu li:hover .submenu li:nth-child(2) {
        -webkit-transition-delay: 50ms;
        -moz-transition-delay: 50ms;
        -ms-transition-delay: 50ms;
        -o-transition-delay: 50ms;
        transition-delay: 50ms;
    }
    .menu li:hover .submenu li:nth-child(3) {
        -webkit-transition-delay: 100ms;
        -moz-transition-delay: 100ms;
        -ms-transition-delay: 100ms;
        -o-transition-delay: 100ms;
        transition-delay: 100ms;
    }
    .menu li:hover .submenu li:nth-child(4) {
        -webkit-transition-delay: 150ms;
        -moz-transition-delay: 150ms;
        -ms-transition-delay: 150ms;
        -o-transition-delay: 150ms;
        transition-delay: 150ms;
    }
    .menu li:hover .submenu li:nth-child(5) {
        -webkit-transition-delay: 200ms;
        -moz-transition-delay: 200ms;
        -ms-transition-delay: 200ms;
        -o-transition-delay: 200ms;
        transition-delay: 200ms;
    }
    .menu li:hover .submenu li:nth-child(6) {
        -webkit-transition-delay: 250ms;
        -moz-transition-delay: 250ms;
        -ms-transition-delay: 250ms;
        -o-transition-delay: 250ms;
        transition-delay: 250ms;
    }
    .menu li:hover .submenu li:nth-child(7) {
        -webkit-transition-delay: 300ms;
        -moz-transition-delay: 300ms;
        -ms-transition-delay: 300ms;
        -o-transition-delay: 300ms;
        transition-delay: 300ms;
    }
    .menu li:hover .submenu li:nth-child(8) {
        -webkit-transition-delay: 350ms;
        -moz-transition-delay: 350ms;
        -ms-transition-delay: 350ms;
        -o-transition-delay: 350ms;
        transition-delay: 350ms;
    }

    .submenu li:nth-child(1) {
        -webkit-transition-delay: 350ms;
        -moz-transition-delay: 350ms;
        -ms-transition-delay: 350ms;
        -o-transition-delay: 350ms;
        transition-delay: 350ms;
    }
    .submenu li:nth-child(2) {
        -webkit-transition-delay: 300ms;
        -moz-transition-delay: 300ms;
        -ms-transition-delay: 300ms;
        -o-transition-delay: 300ms;
        transition-delay: 300ms;
    }
    .submenu li:nth-child(3) {
        -webkit-transition-delay: 250ms;
        -moz-transition-delay: 250ms;
        -ms-transition-delay: 250ms;
        -o-transition-delay: 250ms;
        transition-delay: 250ms;
    }
    .submenu li:nth-child(4) {
        -webkit-transition-delay: 200ms;
        -moz-transition-delay: 200ms;
        -ms-transition-delay: 200ms;
        -o-transition-delay: 200ms;
        transition-delay: 200ms;
    }
    .submenu li:nth-child(5) {
        -webkit-transition-delay: 150ms;
        -moz-transition-delay: 150ms;
        -ms-transition-delay: 150ms;
        -o-transition-delay: 150ms;
        transition-delay: 150ms;
    }
    .submenu li:nth-child(6) {
        -webkit-transition-delay: 100ms;
        -moz-transition-delay: 100ms;
        -ms-transition-delay: 100ms;
        -o-transition-delay: 100ms;
        transition-delay: 100ms;
    }
    .submenu li:nth-child(7) {
        -webkit-transition-delay: 50ms;
        -moz-transition-delay: 50ms;
        -ms-transition-delay: 50ms;
        -o-transition-delay: 50ms;
        transition-delay: 50ms;
    }
    .submenu li:nth-child(8) {
        -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
        -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
        -ms-transition-delay: 0s;
        -o-transition-delay: 0s;
        transition-delay: 0s;
    }
```

Also, here is the code I use for my fullscreen background:

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}


/*-------------------------
    General Styles
--------------------------*/


html{
    /* This image will be displayed fullscreen */
    background:url('BG.jpg') no-repeat center center;

    /* Ensure the html element always takes up the full height of the browser window */
    min-height:100%;

    /* The Magic */
    background-size:cover;
}

body{
    /* Workaround for some mobile browsers */
    min-height:100%;
}

a, a:visited {
    outline:none;
    color:#1c4f64;
}

a:hover{
    text-decoration:none;
}

section, footer, header{
    display: block;
}


/*----------------------------
    The Footer
-----------------------------*/


footer{
    background-color: #111111;
    bottom: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    height: 45px;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100000;
}

footer h2{
    color: #EEEEEE;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -400px;
    padding: 13px 0 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 540px;
}

footer h2 i{
    font-style:normal;
    color:#888;
}

footer a.tzine,a.tzine:visited{
    color: #999999;
    font-size: 12px;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 16px 0 0 110px;
    position: absolute;
    text-decoration: none;
    top: 0;
}

footer a i{
    color:#ccc;
    font-style: normal;
}

footer a i b{
    color:#c92020;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Any ideas what I should fix so I won't have those problems?

Comment: Could you set up a JSfiddle that shows the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS you have

```
.menu, .menu ul {
   list-style:none;
```

We need to see your HTML but I suspect this is being inherited and therefore is why your numbered list and bullets are not working.